# Why are so many questions around nvidia graphics closed with alibi reasons?

Tags: discussion

All the questions with stability issues around nvidia graphics and unity 3D are closed for some strange reasons which seem to be alibis to me.
It seems that nvidia HW was supported well with Ubuntu 11.04 for example (at least for me and many other users) and with 12.04 many many people are complaining NVIDIA support regarding stability at least with older HW.
For me the live system of Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't even work stable without any requirements with my Toshiba Tecra S5 (NVIDIA Quadro 130 M, e.g. no status bar no launcher, compiz crashes etc.)

Answer (score 7):

I don't see that many closed questions when you look at the overall tag:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nvidia

Either way, the examples you cite are problems with Nvidia that we have no control over. Crashes and so on should be reported on the bug tracker, not here. This isn't a place to track Nvidia issues, it's a question and answer site!

Comment: So what's the reason that in former Ubuntu versions the inadequateness of nvidia drivers didn't take effect in that way? Does unity 3D utilize more 3D functions than before?

Comment: Not sure, for example on my Nvidia system it works fine, which is why we send people to the bug tracker that can automatically send all the crash/debug data to developers.

Comment: Ok, I have been sending those reports from the beginnung of the problems and will continue to do so hoping for a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to encourage the use of ubuntu developed drivers and discourage use of closed source drivers!?  especially in newer flavours (hint:  nouveau dependencies)
some of the material my opinion is based on is from here http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/steamd-penguins/ ....  the rest is from just trying different drivers! Some comments in the blog more than hint at there will be suitable drivers for gaming soon... that do not break unity/compiz/windows mangement (because of nouveau dependencies)...

Comment: I don't search for drivers for gaming and as I wrote above I use ubuntu default OPEN SOURCE drivers (nouoveau/gallium) so I don't understand your post I guess.